# how to select class name from button of span using css selector in below code as follows and have received an error

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

how to select class name from button of span using css selector in below code as follows and have received an error.

```
<span class="input-group-btn-vertical">   
   <button class="btn btn-white bootstrap-touchspin-up " type="button">+</button>   
   <button class="btn btn-white bootstrap-touchspin-down " type="button">-</button>
</span>

this.demoTestBailrafting = function (browser) {
    browser
        .url('https://www.phptravels.net/')
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 500)
        .assert.title('PHPTRAVELS | Travel Technology Partner')

        /*trying to select first element in button tag of span class*/

        .click('span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]')
        .pause(500)
        .end()
    };
```

> ERROR: Unable to locate element: 
>   "span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]" 
>   using: css selector

Comment: What error are you getting? What have you already tried? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Greg, Am trying in css selector please assist for resolution
```
this.demoTestBailrafting = function (browser) {   browser
       .url('https://www.phptravels.net/')
       .waitForElementVisible('body', 500)
       .assert.title('PHPTRAVELS | Travel Technology Partner')
       
       /*trying to select first element in button tag of span class*/
       
       .click('span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]')
       .pause(500)
       .end()
 };
```

ERROR: Unable to locate element: 
"span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]" using: css selector

Comment: Please edit your question and add all relevant info inside the question itself so that future readers don't have to read through all comments to get the necessary info to answer the question.

Comment: @Jeffc:
```
this.demoTestBailrafting = function (browser) {   
browser
.url('https://www.phptravels.net/')
.waitForElementVisible('body', 500)
.assert.title('PHPTRAVELS | Travel Technology Partner')
/*trying to select 1st element in btn tag of span class*/
.click('span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]')
.pause(500)
 .end()
};
```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: 
"span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]" 
using: css selector

Comment: I saw what you posted the first time... but you posted it in the comments (like you just did again). Please read my comment carefully... edit your question and post the code there and properly format it. DON'T post it in the comments.

Comment: @Jeffc: since am using for firstime done with format as request now. please check

Comment: Looks pretty good. I tweaked it a bit. Take a look at it and make sure that I didn't mess anything up.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the `class` attribute from both of the buttons below the span -- not sure what language you are using here. But you should be able to use the `getAttribute` function on `WebElement` object.

```
List<IWebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//span[@class='input-group-btn-vertical']/button"));

foreach(IWebElement button in buttons)
{
    // this is the class name
    string className = button.getAttribute("class");
}
```

Comment: I am trying in css selector please resolve below error
```
this.demoTestBailrafting = function (browser) {
   browser
       .url('https://www.phptravels.net/')
       .waitForElementVisible('body', 500)
       .assert.title('PHPTRAVELS | Travel Technology Partner')
       
       /*trying to select first element in button tag of span class*/
       
       .click('span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]')
       .pause(500)
       .end()
 };
```

ERROR: Unable to locate element: 
"span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]" using: css selector

Comment: am getting an error ERROR: Unable to locate element: 
"span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]" using: css selector

Comment: Your locator is probably wrong. try the XPath I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Cristine: I suppose to use css selector instead of xpath so please provide alternate solution if possible.

Comment: I have a requirement to select button tag first element thru css selector, so please advise.

Comment: @Cristine:  ''.click('span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]')'' when I used the  code it says error message "ERROR: Unable to locate element: "span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]" using: cssselector"

Comment: The person's answer below explains this. They clearly stated that the [1] is not valid CSS selector syntax. Please read their answer.

Comment: :,'.click('span.input-group-btn-vertical>button')' As Jeff suggested have tried it says an error "ERROR: Unable to locate element: "span.input-group-btn-vertical>button" using: css selector at Object.demoTestBailrafting (/root/nightwatchSetup/tests/sample.js:16:9) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)"

Answer (score 1):

Your click method

```
.click('span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]')
```

is apparently expecting a CSS selector based on the error message

```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "span[class=input-group-btn-vertical]>button[1]" using: css selector
                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The index `[1]` that you have in your CSS selector isn't valid. It's also not needed here since you are looking for the first element and Selenium will always act on the first element unless you otherwise specify. Also, to make your CSS selector more CSS-like (and more flexible), you should change it to

```
span.input-group-btn-vertical > button
    ^ this dot indicates a class name follows
                                      ^ I removed the [1] since it's not needed
```

See if that works now.

Comment: I have to select the button class first element using css selector not the span class name.

Comment: I specifically stated that it's a CSS selector. Your CSS selector also specifies the SPAN class name. I don't understand the confusion or what you are trying to say.

Comment: I have to select like below .click('button[.btn.btn-white bootstrap-touchspin-up ]') however it displayed an error. unable to find element

Comment: That's because that's not a valid CSS selector.

Comment: I have a requirement to select button tag first element, please advise.

Comment: I already gave you the answer... in my answer. Try it and let me know if it works. If it doesn't please post the error message.

Comment: '.click('span.input-group-btn-vertical>button')' As you suggested have tried it says an error "ERROR: Unable to locate element: "span.input-group-btn-vertical>button" using: css selector
    at Object.demoTestBailrafting (/root/nightwatchSetup/tests/sample.js:16:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)"

Comment: Looks like you either need to add a wait for clickable and then click or check the page and make sure that your element is not inside an IFRAME.